# How do I get started with SyntaxNet in Tensor Flow

Tags: tensorflow, syntaxnet

With Google's rollout of their NLU program SyntaxNet and the English Parser Parsey McParseface. How do I start with the training model?

Comment: Get started with the code; https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet

Blogpost: http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2016/05/announcing-syntaxnet-worlds-most.html

P.S. I don't think this question should be here.

Comment: Thanks. There's no option to delete, so I'm flagging it.

Comment: Compared to many other questions, I do not see its too broad. In order to get started you can read the documentations here:https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet#installation and follow this small post : http://www.whycouch.com/2016/07/how-to-install-and-use-syntaxnet-and.html

Comment: useful question, I ended up here after a similar search.